# when overwrite -> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteObject operation: Access Denied

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have this error: `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteObject operation: Access Denied` - **but** only when I have files in **S3**. When I delete them all, then `python manage.py collectstatic` works fine and uploads files to **S3**.

I want to be able to update my staticfiles when I'm updating my **CSS, HTML** code without the additional effort of deleting stuff on **S3**.

My **S3** policies (from what I've read they should be ok):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::django-python-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Things I've tried without any success:

1. Add to **settings.py:** `AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None`
2. update my policies on **S3** to:

```
{ 
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
   {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectAcl",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::django-python-bucket/*"
    ]
   }
 ]
}
```

Comment: You should probably have two distinct sets of AWS permissions here. One set for use when you deploy your solution (it would be able to delete and put objects) and a second set for the running app (it would be able to get objects, assuming that getting/downloading files from S3 is a feature of your app).

Comment: By the way, that S3 bucket policy is very dangerous because it has Principal:* and allows anyone to upload, get, or delete objects at will.

Comment: Check the django storages documentation for S3, but you might need  s3:GetBucketLocation and/or s3:ListBucket on arn:aws:s3:::django-python-bucket.

Comment: You were right! Thank you. Additionally: I just figured out how to set access just for the admin group, but when I tried the same for "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject" dict, my CSS failed. About `Principal:*` - honestly, I'm fairly new to S3. Isn't it so that the action of modifying, reading and deleting is only possible for the administrator? Is it possible to carry out these actions only in this context? Is there a risk that the user can also perform them, having only access to the form where he/she can submit posts, emails? I will attach my partial solution below (still with one `Principal:*`).

Comment: No, `Principal:*` means anyone, authenticated or not, admin or not. You can read more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/s3-bucket-user-policy-specifying-principal-intro.html). That's acceptable for GetObject if you want to make your objects world-readable but it's almost never appropriate for PutObject, DeleteObject or any mutating action. Those permissions should typically only be available to the relevant IAM users/groups/roles associated with actual AWS account users (not the public).

Comment: I see, but how can I serve static files for users with the help of an S3 bucket and at the same time restrict authorisation in a such way as to be in the middle ground? I.e. to make a page fully operative without security risks? I have set up my bucket to have two folders: media and static. At this moment media are used for uploaded images by content creators/admins. Static has all static files. Things related to users' actions are saved in AWS RDS. I see you updated your answer. Please check out my solution below: is it safe according to your guidance?

Comment: You use an S3 bucket policy to make `static/` objects publicly readable and you use IAM policies to give permission to admins/developers within the AWS account. How your app's users upload their content to the `media/` folder in S3 depends on the nature of your app and how your users authenticate (e.g. via Cognito). Some guidance [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/uploading-to-amazon-s3-directly-from-a-web-or-mobile-application/).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the guidance of **@jarmod** I found a solution.
With the help of [allowing an IAM user access to one of your buckets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-policies-s3.html) and [IAM user principals](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html) I update my **S3** policy, using my IAM group **ARN** instead of risky `"Principal": "*"`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::6663FAKE_ID660666:user/django-python-admin-user"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::django-python-bucket"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::django-python-bucket/*"
        }
```

Now I'm able to use `python manage.py collectstatic`.